# submit ajax using anchor tag to spring mvc controller

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to apply ajax with my spring mvc, but couldn't find where I make thing wrong. I try to follow several tutorials but couldn't customize mine to work. It always falls to error state.

So this is my ajax call

```
function doAjax() {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    var json = {
            "username" : useranme, 
            "email" : email, 
            "password" : password
    }
    //alert("username: " + username + "  email: " + email + " password: " + password);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('form').attr('action'),
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function(data) {
        },
        error:function(data, status, err) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
};
```

And this is my form:

```
<div class="form">
        <spring:url var="registerUrl" value="http://localhost:9004/Project/register" htmlEscape="true" />
        <form method="post" action="${registerUrl}">
            <div class="form_field">
                <label for="username">Username</label><br/>
                <input class="field" id="username" type="text" name="userName" autocomplete="off"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form_field">
                <label for="email">Email</label><br/>
                <input class="field" id="email" type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="form_field">
                <label for="password">Password</label><br/>
                <input class="field" id="password" type="password" name="password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form_field prefix_clear">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
                <input id="submit" class="action_button" type="submit" value="Register"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <a href="#" id="button12" onClick="doAjax()" class="action_button">Click me</a>
    </div>
```

So if I submit the form using the input, it works perfectly. But it doesn's work when I try to submit it using anchor tag. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To make your ajax call work exactly as a form submit, you should, instead of using the JSON, just replace your *data:JSON.stringify* to

```
data:$("form").serialize();
```

If you have to make a request with JSON data, than you'll have to edit your question with the mapping method and command object to get help, but one thing that is obviously wrong with your code, is that you're not including the *_csrf* parameters in your ajax request